# Nothing happens on back button click on Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

When back button is clicked on the Toolbar nothing happens. I dont know whats the problem.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notices For Students");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the back button is nothing more than a menu item so you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected`

and look for when the button is pressed in there and do something like this

```
if(menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using this:

```
  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

here i'm finishing when user click on back.

Kindly use this and tell me if you may face any problem.